# Iphone app test scrolling

Tags: android, iphone, scrolling

I’m designing a test for an iphone and android app.
The test consists of 10 questions. Each question has 3 answers, A,B and C.  The length of the question and the answers are variable and pulled randomly from a database.

After each question there is a previous and next button.

Some questions are long so the previous and next buttons are not visible without scrolling. If I positioned the previous and next buttons at the top of the app then in some cases the third answer (C ) would not be visible without scrolling.

My initial idea was to automatically load the next question when a user clicks on a answer however I still need a previous button.

I haven’t built a prototype yet so not sure how much of a big deal the scrolling issue is however I’d be very interested to hear of any suggestions.

Comment: What specifically is your question? I assume you're asking how to solve the issue of answers/buttons appearing too far down the page?

Answer (score 3):

You could use left and right swipe gestures to move between questions.

This functionality can be inferred from dots on the bottom of the question indicating the page you're on (like the iPhone's home screen). Users on smartphones are keen to these visual cues.

You could even use these indicators to show whether or not the user has answered the question on that page (grayed out if not, green if yes, maybe?)

Also, you can point out this functionality in an intro page as Bart suggests.

Answer (score 1):

My idea: putting the Next button below the answer seems to be the most logical to me.

The sequence of the actions a user performs are:

1. Read the question
2. Answer the question
3. Go to the next question.

It makes sense to reflect this sequence in the UI. Therefor the Next button needs to go at the bottom. The back button goes along with the Next button since it's also a kind of navigation button, so put that to the left of the Next button.

As far as the scrolling is concerned: I think it is safe to assume that an iPhone or Android user understands the concept of scrolling.

The only problem then remains is that if the first question is long enough for the Back and Next buttons to be out of the visible area, but the question and answers are visible, the user does not know he needs to scroll. Simple solution: Add an introduction page, something like "Hello and Welcome -- you will be asked a series of questions blablabla... Click Next to get started". Put the Next button below as in the questions. This trains the user where the position of the Next button is. Of course, you have to make sure that in the introduction page, the Next button is directly visible.

Comment: Thank you Bart. I like your introduction page idea, I think that will work nicely :-)